# Accessing the Iterator interface in PHP 5.2.17

Tags: php, iterator

Currently we have to use PHP 5.2. Yes, I know I ought to upgrade to 5.3 or 5.4 but, in the meantime:

I'm trying to write my own class that implements the Iterator interface. However, the class cannot be found, apparently because the Iterator interface is not loaded. However, SPL is loaded which I thought was sufficient.

Any suggestions? Doubtless I've missed something stupid...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have a simple example that doesn't work? Does the [example from the PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php) works?

Comment: Can yuo provide the code of your implementation of Iterator? Which is exactly the error you get?

Comment: My code now loods rather simple, as I've stripped out all the code. I've ended up with a class that looks like this:

class MyClass implements Iterator {
   // All the Iterator operations implemented
}

When I attempt to instantiate MyClass I get:

Fatal error:  Class 'MyClass' not found in ...

Commenting out the "implements Iterator" removes the error. (Although, of course it now isn't an Iterator which was the point.)

Answer (score 1):

The iterator is not a class, it's an interface:

```
class Yourclass implements Iterator {

  // Methods here

}
```

If this didn't solve the issue, you should consider actually including some code in your question.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like an old bug (not fixed) when using turkish locale : https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=18556

If so, try using another locale.